# Installing new version of NodeJS on Lubuntu 20.04 LTS - How to avoid possible problems?

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, nodejs

I am using Lubuntu 20.04 LTS and I have installed NodeJS from package manager. Apparently, the latest release available was NodeJS `v10.19.0`, I need to update to latest `NodeJS LTS (v14)` but not sure how to proceed.
I have read many "how to install latest nodejs" question and articles but nobody says anything about:

Should I remove the current version before installing the new one? Or it doesn't matter? Can I have compatibility issues or something, given that this version is not officially supported by Ubuntu yet?  And should I do anything to `npm`?

I was thinking in doing the following:

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

As suggested in the nodesource github

Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: I would use [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm): it lets you switch between node & npm versions at ease, according to which project needs which version; something that will come essential if you need node for projects that are not your one-person projects (e.g. ones that you cloned from github). ["Option 3" in this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-20-04#option-3-%E2%80%94-installing-node-using-the-node-version-manager) is an efficient walkaround on the topic.

Comment: So nvm allows me to install multiple versions so that I avoid having any trouble? Sort of virtual-envs? I don't know about node/npm versions differences either, could you elaborate? (I am really just starting with this) Thanks

Comment: "I avoid having any trouble" — right, as far as I know, it does not conflict with any Ubuntu conventions: basically frees you from headaches (or at least it worked such on Ubuntu when I relied on it a lot a few years ago). "Sort of virtual-envs?" — well, technically not, but the experience is comparable. It can switch node / npm version through a single terminal command; very convenient. "I don't know about node/npm versions differences" — different projects will declare dependency on different node / npm versions; if you work on such, you need to be able to switch.

Comment: One of the problems I faced with the nvm is that it increases terminal loading time significantly, even vscode was complaining about it. The best way is to go as per the nodesource installation guides